# Will a Xeon X3360 CPU be compatible with my ASUS P5MT-M?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, virtualization, compatibility

[Link to CPU Specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/33933/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X3360-%2812M-Cache-2_83-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB%29)

[Link to Motherboard Specs](http://www.asus.com/Server_Workstation/Server_Motherboards/P5MTM/)

I want to confirm that this will work before I purchase the CPU.

I don't want to upgrade my motherboard/RAM/power supply, unless I have to. I just need a CPU that supports Intel VT for this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's not a single Xeon CPU listed under the "CPU Support List" in the link you provided for the motherboard, I'm going to have to say No, it won't work.

At the link you provided for the CPU, Intel states that the required Intel chipset for this processor is either the 3200 and 3210 with ICH9, neither of which are on that board.

There are a few other reasons that this chip won't work, even though it may fit in the socket. :)

Answer (score 1):

The CPU you have mentioned does not feature on the Motherboards supported CPU list.

For that reason alone I'd be inclined to say no, especially given the difference in age between the two components.

I've not experience to comment on though that's just based on the documentation you have provided.